# Problems loading reference 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/jsconfig.json': unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am trying to create a "Hello World" program. in LWC but i was getting a error in jsconfig.json file. the error is `Problems loading reference 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/jsconfig.json': unable to get local issuer certificate`

[image]

But I have did same as in Trailhead [Create a Hello World Lightning Web Component](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component)

Is there a way to fix it?....